# How to do multiple logistic regression and show each variable odds ratio table?

Tags: r, glm

Everyone, my df is like:

[image]

or you can copy it:

```
reg_df <- structure(list(NEWDI = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), age = c(79.93, 75.1, 
59.52, 45.62, 63.25, 69.41, 70.37, 70.57, 72.54, 64.63, 67.41, 
60.29, 71.52, 65.11, 73.52, 57.96, 75.88, 65.35, 73.23, 57.25
), smoke_dummy = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), drink_dummy = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), bmi = c(27.9595, 32.7313, 28.682, 26.8898, 30.556, 25.763, 
26.9286, 45.3568, 33.1924, 29.391, 36.0282, 25.7202, 35.2501, 
27.0999, 35.5935, 30.1911, 32.557, 28.0998, 25.2214, 23.4699), 
    edu_dummy = c(0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 
    0L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, NA), class_dummy = c(3, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0), sex_dummy = c(1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data. Frame")
```

I want to do this:

```
model <- glm(NEWDI ~ class_dummy + age + smoke_dummy + drink_dummy +
              bmi + edu_dummy  + sex_dummy,
             data = reg_df, family = "binomial")

summary(model)
```

I have question:

I want to set each X variable value is 0 as the reference group for
regression and see their  ORs(except class_dummy value is 0~3, other
variable_dummy values are 0~1.), and smoke_dummy, drink_dummybmi, edu_dummy and bmi have NA value, I'm not sure if regression can be set to ignore NA values.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think your data is appropriate for logistic regression because the dependent variable (or Y variable)`NEWDI` only have 0. 

Q1, Q3. If you want to find the OR table, you could check regression table packages such as `gtsummary`.

Q2. regression functions like `glm()` excludes NA values. You could find the message `9 observations deleted due to missingness` at the `summary(model)`.

Comment: Asking multiple questions isn't allowed in SO. Please [edit] your post and focus on one question that is more explained

Comment: @YHJang Thank you, I didn't notice that the first 20 items of the sample data are all 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show reference group in regression, you need to change `_dummy` variable as factor. I did this using `data.table`.

Next, after fit the model, you can create the regression table using `tbl_regression` in `gtsummary` package.

```
library(data.table)
library(gtsummary)


target <- grep(pattern = "_dummy", names(reg_df), value = T)

setDT(reg_df)[,(target) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols=target]

model <- glm(NEWDI ~ class_dummy + age + smoke_dummy + drink_dummy +
               bmi + edu_dummy  + sex_dummy,
             data = reg_df, family = "binomial")


tbl_regression(
  model,
  exponentiate = T,
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the dummy variable could be set from glm, but I had to use data. Table separately.

Comment: Sorry, I found out that "gtsummary" makes pictures, is there other package that can save the model results to csv format?

Comment: You can drag and copy the result of the regression model. Is it okay?

Comment: I found that I can use `gtsummary::as_tibble()` to set it, and use `write_xlsx` to do it. Thank you.